# Publishing to Azure fails after Azure locked me out of my virtual machine and forced me to reset my password

Tags: azure, windows-authentication, windows-server

I woke and tried to log into my Azure Win Server VM with Microsoft Remote Desktop, but couldn't authenticate with my password! I received no message in Windows leading up to it saying I needed to change my password or anything!

Anyone know why?

So, I created a support ticket and after speaking to the guy on the phone, all he could do was recommend I reset my password in the Azure dashboard, which I did.

So I reset the password, logged in and then tried to publish my site and some supporting Azure functions and they all failed saying 'authentication failed' WTF!! It seems like when I reset my windows password, other passwords for publishing my site and Azure functions were changed as well.

Is this typical or have I set up all my publishing in a non typical fashion?

So now to publish I had to re download the publish profiles.

I hope this doesn't happen again! What if I was live...

Here is what the error looks like in Visual Studio when I try and publish

> Connected to the remote computer ("myservicefunctions.scm.azurewebsites.net") using the Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using the correct user name and password

Comment: Authorisation is complicated in Azure and it's quite unclear what has really happened here as your explanation crosses a whole lot of different platforms with very little detail. No it's not normal for logins to just stop working.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that Windows wanted me to update my password, but never showed any popup window saying so, or I get hacked into and someone else changed my password. But the second scenario seems very unlikely.